# Sample size vs. Number of samples (how many samples of size n will prove statistically significant results?)

Tags: statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, sampling, descriptive-statistics

I understand that although I take a SRS, unless my population is normally distributed, having a sample size less than 30 is not ideal. Thus, if I take an SRS of 10 days, how many samples of these 10 days would I need to take in order for my results to be statistically significant? I know a large number of samples is ideal, but how many is too small? For example, if I take 25 SRS’s of size 10 is that too small? Or if I take 10 SRS’s of size 10, is that enough?

Comment: Please don't use jargon. What is SRS?

Comment: It depends on SD $\sigma$ of the population and what difference $\Delta$ in mean you want to be reasonably sure to detect. // If you're still interested in this, please give some specifics and I'll try to answer.